# Button Matrix / Wiring Schematics

Tags: arduino-uno, button, wires

I am just beginning my journey into the Arduino world - plenty of development experience, but basically nothing with electronics outside of building computers.

The question I have involves wiring schematics - specifically for a button matrix, but it does apply more broadly. Using this diagram and Fritzing mapping, I see numerous buttons connected to each other - presumably via soldering:

[image: Diagram]

[image: Fritzing]

My question is, can you use wire nuts (or, more specifically multi-slot lever connectors) such as these to simplify the connection process?

[image: Levers]

I apologize in advance if this seems obvious, but I get lost trying to understand how to connect this stuff because I'm so new to it all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: that keypad can only detect one button press at a time ... if you press two buttons at once, then up to four button presses can be detected ... a diode at each switch can be used to prevent "ghost" button presses

Comment: Woah - good to know @jstola! I'm going to start looking into diodes now. So much to learn, but luckily this first project is mainly for a button/busy box for my 18-month old kid, so he's going to smash all the buttons and not care as much on whether they do everything individually or not. Definitely an excellent tip though!

Comment: if you are expecting to press only one button at a time, then you can use a resistor array ... the input to the arduino would be a single wire connected to an analog input pin

Comment: Yet another thing I didn't know existed! This would make wiring SO much easier by not having to deal with so many individual resistors. If I could give you points on here, I totally would. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "multi-slot lever connectors" is shorting the inserted wires together I see no reason why you could not use them.

If you are adverse to soldering consider using switches and cables commonly found in arcade machines instead.

Previously crimped cables ...

[image]

And arcade style micro switches ...

[image]

Can be combined / connected to form the switch matrix your designed above.

Comment: Fantastic - I didn't even know these existed. Thank you!